# Assigning value to variable in x86 (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have decided to learn assembler for fun. I have been coding in C for many years.

I followed some online tutorials that print "Hello world" and dug around a bit in the NASM manual. All well and good. So, I set myself a task of printing "hello world" in a loop. I know I can do this with the `loop` opcode, but wanted to code it explicitly and use variables defined in the `.bss` section.

However, I obviously misunderstand how variable assignment works in assembly as I get the error message:

```
nasm -felf -o hello.o hello.asm
hello.asm:16: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
hello.asm:17: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
hello.asm:28: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

I have tried searching the web for info on variable assignment, including the NASM manual, but can't seem to find the information I need. Can anyone assist? Here's my (simple!) code:

```
; print "Hello world!" to the screen multiple times

section .data
    msg:    db  'Hello world!', 10
    msglen: equ $ - msg

section .bss
    iter:   resb    1

section .text
    global _start

_start:

    ; loop 10 times
    mov iter, 0     ; initalise loop counter
FL: cmp iter, 10    ; is iter == 10?
    jge LoopEnd

    ; write the message to STDOUT:
    mov eax,4       ; code for write syscall
    mov ebx,1       ; stdout fd
    mov ecx,msg     ; message to print...
    mov edx,msglen  ; ...and it's length
    int 80h         ; kernel interrupt

    ; increment loop iterator
    inc iter
    jp FL

LoopEnd:


    ; now exit, with return code 0:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make a memory reference in nasm, you must surround the address with square brackets. Additionally, in each of the cases you've got here, you also need to specify a size, like so:

```
    mov byte [iter], 0     ; initalise loop counter
FL: cmp byte [iter], 10    ; is iter == 10?

    inc byte [iter]
```

In this case, though, it would probably make more sense to store `iter` in a register instead of in memory. You're clobbering most of the obvious ones with your system calls, but `esi` or `edi` look available.

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it. It's a bit like c pointer de-referencing then? 'iter' is the address, but [iter] is the data at the address? yes? I dont see why I need to tell it that iter is a byte though - i defined it as a byte in the .bss section. I will look up the answer to that in the manual though! yes - I could have done it with a register, but I wanted to use a variable from the .bss section just to prove i could! thanks.

Comment: `iter` is just an address. Specifically, the address of that one byte you `resb`'d. So its up to you to specify how big of a memory access you are making. This is assembly man, nothing is really done for you :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think it has to be in brackets. Try `[iter]`.

See the [NASM docs](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-language.html) whenever you have questions like this.

In this case, the section on [Effective Addresses](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html):

> An effective address is any operand to an instruction which references memory. Effective addresses, in NASM, have a very simple syntax: they consist of an expression evaluating to the desired address, enclosed in square brackets. For example:

```
wordvar dw 123
mov ax,[wordvar]
mov ax,[wordvar+1]
mov ax,[es:wordvar+bx]
```